# How to pass the data of an attribute still input field?

Tags: jquery

How can I get through code jQuery the attribute data `data-target` only by clicking on it link:

```
<a id="dateCalendar" class="dateCalendar" data-target="2020-11-18">Data 1</a>
<a id="dateCalendar" class="dateCalendar" data-target="2020-11-15">Data 2</a>
```

And, that value is replaced if I click on another label `a`, I want to obtain said value in a field `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass element context to the function using onClick method. You can set JS global variable and set data-target to that. Then, Set value to the input field.

```
     <a id="dateCalendar" onClick="setDataTarget(this)" class="dateCalendar" data-target="2020-11-18">Data 1</a>
     <a id="dateCalendar" onClick="setDataTarget(this)"  class="dateCalendar" data-target="2020-11-15">Data 2</a>
        
     <input id="text1" type="text" onclick="getValue()" value="">

        var dataTarget;
        function setDataTarget(elem){
            dataTarget= $(elem).attr("data-target");
        }

        function getValue(){
           $("#text1").val(dataTarget);

        }
```

Comment: that value as I send it to a field: `form input`

Comment: Obtaining the values I already knew, now what I need is to pass this information or whatever I click to an input field like this for example: `<input type ="text" name="name" value= "2020-11-15 ">`

Comment: I want to obtain this value data-target = "2020-11-15" automatically when I click and if I give another value the value is updated